# Resolve 'Building Unnamed' in Maven

Tags: maven

While building project with Maven, i see the log as below:
Building Unnamed - com.mycompany.myproject:module:jar:1.0.

How can i resolve 'Unnamed'? where to add a configuration to name it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `<name/>` element in your pom.xml containing the name you would like to see.